# Python Kivy ftplib Exception

Tags: android, python, windows, kivy

My code looks like this

```
import ftplib
server = ftplib.FTP(url)
```

`server = ftplib.FTP(url)` raises the following error:

```
socket.gaierror: 
[Errno 4] non-recoverable failure in name resolution.
```

The server is reachable via chrome and Firefox. What is wrong with my code? I use python 2.7.4 and kivy on android with kivy launcher.

Full stack trace is:

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /storage/emulated/0/kivy/SchollChat Mobile/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-05-23_10.txt
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.0
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.2 (default, Apr  2 2015, 13:52:41) 
[GCC 4.8]
[INFO              ] Factory: 173 symbols loaded
[WARNING           ] stderr: /data/data/org.kivy.pygame/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
[WARNING           ] stderr: (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] Window: Provider: pygame
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@45.0 AU@ (CL@)>
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 305>
[INFO              ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO              ] GL: Texture max size <4096>
[INFO              ] GL: Texture max units <16>
[INFO              ] Support: Android install hooks
[INFO              ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO              ] Text: Provider: pygame
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 117, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:     server = ftplib.FTP(url)
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 132, in connect
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
[WARNING           ] stderr: socket.gaierror: [Errno 4] non-recoverable failure in name resolution.
```

Comment: Can you give a full stack trace?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the stack trace. It's the full kivy error log.

Comment: Got it. It's the encoding from my config file where get my url. On windows new line is \n but android sees it as a [] character. So i changed it to unix \r and it worked. New line characters are replaced but not the [] so the url could not be found.